# what order do cucumber tests get run

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I know cucumber runs each test in a feature file from top down, but my question is, in what order do feature files get run?  It doesn't seem to be alphabetically, or in any structure order.

Comment: I bet it's a sorted list of `feature` files (with directories, of course) from this string of code: `Dir["#{path}/**/*.feature"].sort` ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [Justin Ko's website](https://jkotests.wordpress.com/2013/08/22/specify-execution-order-of-cucumber-features/), order of execution is determined as follows:

1. Alphabetically by feature file directory
2. Alphabetically by feature file name
3. Order of scenarios within the feature file

Answer (score 1):

Feature files are running in alphabetically order so there is a one way to execute all scenario in a single file like "EndToEnd.feature" where you can specify all scenarios with tags and execute from Runner. Hope it will help you.